# UDP echo on Nucleo STM32F7

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I try to make an UDP echo serveur on NUCLEO-F746ZG but when i start the client, my board make just one answer.

This is my thread code :

```
static void udpecho_thread(void *arg)
{
    err_t err, recv_err;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);

    conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
    if (conn != NULL)
    {
        err = netconn_bind(conn, '0xc0a8b26f', 8);
        if (err == ERR_OK)
        {
            while (1)
            {
                recv_err = netconn_recv(conn, &buf);

                if (recv_err == ERR_OK)
                {
                    addr = netbuf_fromaddr(buf);
                    port = netbuf_fromport(buf);
                    netconn_connect(conn, addr, port);
                    buf->addr.addr = 0;
                    netconn_send(conn, buf);
                    netbuf_delete(buf);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            netconn_delete(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

The client side working on the computer:

```
Hostname 192.168.178.111 resolved as 192.168.178.111

Reply from 192.168.178.111:8, time 46 ms OK
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant

Statistics: Received=1, Corupted=0, Lost=0
```

Comment: I don't get the error message of the PC that translates to "Connection closed by foreign host". Note you're using UDP - That's *connectionless* - Are you maybe mixing TCP and UDP?

Comment: Thanks to you, i mixed TCP and UDP in my program ^^"

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

```
err = netconn_bind(conn, '0xc0a8b26f', 8);
```

is called only at the start of your thread and then inside is while loop which works all the time. For example, only 1 execution is allowed.

You might consider rewriting this function to something similar to this:

```
static void udpecho_thread(void *arg) {
    err_t err, recv_err;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);
    while (1) { /* Add this loop */
        conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
        if (conn != NULL) {
            err = netconn_bind(conn, '0xc0a8b26f', 8);
            if (err == ERR_OK) {
                while (1) {
                    recv_err = netconn_recv(conn, &buf);

                    if (recv_err == ERR_OK) {
                        addr = netbuf_fromaddr(buf);
                        port = netbuf_fromport(buf);
                        netconn_connect(conn, addr, port);
                        buf->addr.addr = 0;
                        netconn_send(conn,buf);
                        netbuf_delete(buf);
                    } else {
                        break; /* Add break to stop inner loop */
                    }
                }
            }
            netconn_delete(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

*You see, it is very easy to format code*

Comment: I'am still with the same error :  Reply from 192.168.178.111:8, time 32ms OK
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant
Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant

Comment: I really wouldn't know what this shit *Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant* means. Stackoverflow is english oriented language.

Comment: Sorry, the connection is lost beteween the card(serveur) and the computer (client). I don't understand why i can receive 1 packet and not a lot ? I try in TCP protocole and it's working...

Comment: I'have still the same problem, just one packet and not more... :/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for an EchoServeur is :

```
static void udpecho_thread(void *arg) {
    err_t err, recv_err;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);
    while (1) { /* Add this loop */
        conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
        if (conn!= NULL) {
            err = netconn_bind(conn, '0xc0a8b26f', 8);
            if (err == ERR_OK) {
                while (1) {
                    recv_err = netconn_recv(conn, &buf);

                    if (recv_err == ERR_OK) {
                        addr = netbuf_fromaddr(buf);
                        port = netbuf_fromport(buf);
                        netconn_sendto(conn,buf,addr,port);

                        netbuf_delete(buf);
                    }
                }
            } else  {
                netconn_delete(conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```